# Find the most common string sequence in a SQL datatable column of open-ended responses

Tags: sql, r, text-mining

I have a SQL column with open-ended payment memos written by customers. I want to filter out the memos that indicate a user was paid through "Square" as opposed to memos indicating user was paid for say a "Square tablecloth".

I suspect that frequently recurring strings might provide signal of square payment vs square shaped product. Just eyeballing I see lots of "Square payment" and "square transaction". **How can I evaluate and rank the most frequently recurring string patterns in a column like this?** Most memos are < 100 characters long but with 36 alphanumeric English characters (excluding punctuation and capitals) ... 100^36 is a large number of combinations to compare for relative frequency.

I can access these data in SQL and in R if there are any proposed solutions. Thank you.

Comment: What SQL product (Oracle, MS-SQL, mySQL, etc.)

Comment: Vertica and Hive

Comment: Can you replace "square (space) word" with "square_word" and then use a wordcloud library in R? Not sure if that would work well but just an initial thought.

Comment: (1) Possibly `select ... where memo not like '%square%pay%'` (order matters). (2) `select ... where (memo not like '%square%' or memo like '%pay%')`. (3) Beyond that, you may need to revert to regex, for which solid examples would be useful (including true-positive, true-negative, and completely-unrelated memos).